# Determining % agreement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to determine the percentage of time that a value for different entries in a table match. For example, with the following simple table:

```
User     Question   Answer
-----------------------------------
Tony      1         Yes
Bill      1         No
Jeff      2         Cat
Tony      2         Dog
Bill      2         Dog
Tony      3         No
```

I would like to write a query that tells me that Tony and Bill agree 50% of the time on the two questions that they have both answered.

Comment: Conceptually, restrict the relation to the eligible questions (i.e., where they both answered), then count the total number of questions (i.e., distinct question numbers) and the number of _answers by Tony_ where Bill agreed. I'm not experienced enough with SQL to write that out, but it should be a guide to where to go…

Comment: What are the parameters to the query? The user names, the question number, or is this one of those brobdingnagian joins that are only necessary to answer uni exam questions that should output a row for every combination of a pair of users and question?

Comment: @millimoose +1 for “brobdingnagian”; love that word!

Comment: Parameters should just be two usernames. Say there are 100 questions in the same table, each with a QID, a UID, and an Answer. I just want to pass in two UIDs. From that it would be great to get back the following info: 

UID1 Answered 85 questions, UID2 Answered 90 questions, UID1 and UID2 Answered 80 same questions, UID1 answers matched UID2 answers 60 times, UID1 and UID2 match rate is 75%

Answer (score 3):

`'Tony'` is the User1 parameter,

`'Bill'` is the User2 parameter:

---

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.user = 'Tony' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS U1_Total_Questions,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.user = 'Bill' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS U2_Total_Questions,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN b.user IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Total_Same_Questions,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.answer = b.answer THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Total_Matched_Answers,
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN a.answer = b.answer THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN b.user IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) * 100 AS Percentage_Agreement
FROM 
    answertbl a
LEFT JOIN
    answertbl b ON a.question = b.question AND a.user = 'Tony' AND b.user = 'Bill'
```

### -

```
U1_Total_Questions  U2_Total_Questions  Total_Same_Questions    Total_Matched_Answers   Percentage_Agreement
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3                   2                   2                       1                       50.0000
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For some reason I'm getting 0% agreement on all, but I may just have a simple error somewhere...

Comment: That some reason is integer division.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  count(case when t1.Answer = t2.Answer then 1 else null end) * 1.0 / count(*)
from
  t t1
  inner join t t2 on t1.Question = t2.Question
where
  t1.[User] = 'Tony'
  and t2.[User] = 'Bill'
```